# Find list of surfaces from a surface, and internal cuts coordinates

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I need to make an application who takes a rectangle with several cuts inside of it.
What I have is :

- coordinates of rectangle ABCD
- List of segments EF, FG and FH.

In that concrete case, I may find that the result are three rectangles AGFE, GBHF and EHCD.

Have an idea how I could procede?

[image]

Comment: Proceed to do what?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Concretely, I use a software to cut details in plates, let's say I cut some details in the "AGFE" square. Then I make 2 cuts "EFG" and "FH", to take back the scraps. I want to calculate the 3 squares resulting, so I can identify the square where are my details(checking details coorinates), and the 2 remaining squares, to know which scraps I have. Main problem is on that software, the only information I have is the coordinates of the final cuts (EFG and FH).